# computational complexity of rejection sampling

Tags: computational-complexity, monte-carlo

I came across the problem to bound the computational complexity of the Monte Carlo rejection sampler, sampling from a proposal distribution $q_T$ rather than the target distribution $p_T$. The two distributions are related by $sup_k \frac{p_T}{q_T} \leq M < \infty$ where $M$ is a known constant. At first glance, I would believe that the number of samples depends only on $M$, specifying how many samples are needed until one is accepted. Ergo, the computational complexity of the Monte-Carlo rejection sampler is bounded by $\mathcal{O}(M)$ but I am not sure if that is true.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Definitely not an area of my expertise, but to perform the rejection sampling, once you sample a point $x \sim q_T$, don't you need to compute the values of both PDFs at that point, and their ratio, and use that ratio as a threshold to decide if $x$ is rejected/accepted?  If so, it seems like the computational complexity depends on the PDFs, as well as the complexity of sampling $x \sim q_T$.

Comment: Precisely, the sampler samples $x \sim q_T$ and $u$ from a Uniform distribution $[0,M q_T]$. The sample is accepted if $u < p_T$.

Comment: So the computational complexity of drawing each sample (whether it is accepted or rejected), is the computational complexity of sampling $x\sim q_T$, plus the computational complexities of computing the values of both PDFs at $x$ (unless you have that for $q_T$ from step 1), plus the complexity of one sampling from a uniform distribution, plus computing the threshold, plus comparing the uniform random variable and the threshold.